# Get it signed by or Get it signed from . What is the correct usage?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Please let me know the correct usage of the sentence . Is it by or from ?

Comment: The correct usage is "get it signed by", not from.

Comment: Can you please explain why

Comment: Either can be correct. An actual  sentence or more of context would help. I get my autograph book *signed from* time to time.

Comment: That's not really "signed from", though.  Those are two separate clauses: *I get my autograph book signed* / *from time to time.*  If we're talking about someone signing a book, then the book is signed *by* the person.  But you're right that more context could help - maybe the OP did see something like your example sentence.

Comment: @stangdon Right, they're separate thingies.  But they're not separate clauses. *From time to time* is a phrase. You're right about the important bit, though – *from* isn't in construction with *signed* there.  They just happen to be linearly adjacent.

Comment: @snailboat - Point taken!  I should have just said "thingies".  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Lack of context is detrimental* to a good answer, so take this with a pinch of salt.

Examples (made up context):

> Mr. Brown? -- Yes, sir. -- Please take this form to Mr. Johnson and **get it signed by** this afternoon.

Here "by" is part of the adjective phrase "by this afternoon", meaning temporal reference, the point at which the form must be already signed.

> Mr. Brown? -- Yes, sir. -- Please take this form to Mr. Johnson and **get it signed by** him, then bring it back.

Here "by" is part of the indirect object of "signed", instrumental case, meaning "he" (Mr. Johnson) is to sign the form.

> Ms. Smith? -- Yes, ma'am. -- I'd like you to go to Mr. Johnson and bring the form 1234AZ **signed from** his office.

Here, there is no grammatical connection between "signed" and "from" because the word "signed" is a post-attribute of the word "form", meaning the form needs to have a signature on it *before* Ms. Smith can bring it "from his office".  The "from" is just a directional preposition suggesting the origin of the signed form.

---

If your question concerned the person who is to sign something (letter, form, book, autograph on a photo), then in most cases we say "by":

> Have you read anything by Hemmingway?  I have a copy of "The Old Man and The Sea" **signed *by* him**, it has been in our family for decades.